# Arguments for mixin in SASS

Tags: css, sass

Just noticed that I cannot use CSS property names as arguments in mixins.
For example, I would like to use something like this:

```
@mixin hover($key,$value) {
    &:hover {
        $key: $value;
    }
}
```

Where `$key` is a CSS property and `$value` is a value of that property.
Instead of it I use this code:

```
@mixin hover-color($value) {
    &:hover {
        color: $value;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to use CSS properties as arguments in mixins or any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
@mixin hover($key,$value) {
    &:hover {
    #{$key}: $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Artem look up interpolation in the sass manual or a sass tutorial